# Dibujar en matriz

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrices

quisiera saber como relleno una matriz de tal forma que pareciera que "dibujo" una figura , se supone que deberia crear la figura y despues "pintarla"(eso se haria por ejemplo poniendole otro numero al "dibujo"), se que para pintar deberia usar (o eso me dijeron) backctraking y he estado leyendo que podria usar Bresenham para "dibujar" en la matriz pero no entiendo mucho como usar ambos metodos, si podrian guiarme se lo agradeceria mucho.

**Actualizacion:** Las figuras que pueden ser solicitadas serian "cuadrado","triangulo","circulo" y "rectangulo", se debe dibujar su contorno y despues mostrarle esa figura rellenada con el "color" que eligio, el usuario solo debe elegir si quiere una figura grande o pequeña
Lo que llevo recien es esto:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def Rombo(n):

    l = [[' ' for x in range(n)] for z in range(n/2+1)]
    for e in range(n):
        for i in range(e,n-e):
            l[e][i] = '*'
    l = l[:0:-1]+l
    for i in l:
        print ' '.join(i)


def Cuadrado(largo,ancho):

   for i in range(largo):
       if i in[0]:
         print("* "*(ancho))
       elif i in[(largo-1)]:
         print("* "*(ancho))
       else:
         print("*"+"  "*(ancho)+" *")

def Opciones():
   op=0
   while op!=1 and op!=2 and op!=9:
     print
     print " Menu de opciones"
     print"-----------------------"
     print "[1] Rombo"
     print "[2] Cuadrado"
     print "[9] terminar la ejecucion"
     op = int(raw_input("ingrese opcion: "))
   return op  

#programa
opcion=Opciones()
while opcion!=9:
   if opcion==1:
       Rombo(21)
   elif opcion==2:
      Cuadrado(6,6) 
   else:
      print"Debe ingresar una opcion valida"
print 'Adios, nos vemos :3'
```

**Nota:** Algo asi seria el menu ,logre implementar el cuadrado y rombo pero no se como detener el bucle infinito para que no se impriman mas , tambien no se como rellenar el cuadrado con el color que quiera el usuario y en el caso del rombo no se me ocurrio como hacerlo que solo muestre los bordes, sino que me sale todo lleno.

Comment: El código está mal indentado (posiblemente debido a un copia&pega defectuoso), por lo que no es posible saber dónde empieza y acaba cada función o bucle. Por favor, edita la pregunta para corregirlo y sigue estas instrucciones para pegarlo correctamente--> https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Comment: Listo, creo que alli ya quedo bien indentado :) , gracias por eso

Comment: Ok, pero no entiendo qué quires dibujar. Supongo que serán figuras geométricas predefinidas, como rectas, círculos o puntos, ya que no hay forma de que el usuario pueda realmente "dibujar" formas libres

Comment: solo hice eso de pedir columnas y filas para guiarme un poco, lo que necesito hacer es por ejemplo ... si el usuario ingresa 1(el cual voy a cambiar para que diga "Cuadrado") le de la opcion de elegir el color con el que lo quiere pintar ejemplo: 1= rojo, 2=azul,3=verde ... y al final le muestre la figura que eligio(en este caso un cuadrado) "pintado" con el color que eligio... no se si se entiende mucho

Comment: Sí, creo que entiendo, pero para poder recibir ayuda deberías poner en la pregunta esta información: qué figuras pueden ser "solicitadas", si hay que dibujar sólo su contorno o rellenadas, si el usuario puede especificar las dimensiones de cada lado... Dibujar rectángulos y cuadrados es bastante sencillo, pero si vas a permitir también líneas que puedan estar inclinadas, necesitarás el algoritmo de Bresenham (si no, no), y para círculos haría falta otro algoritmo, etc.

Comment: Por cierto, que no veo de qué forma lo del _backtracking_ pueda estar relacionado. Yo creo que no lo necesitas para nada.

Comment: Yo tambien pense lo mismo pero me dijeron que debia solucionarlo poniendo en alguna parte backtracking... por eso me perdi mas jajaj

Comment: el circulo no es tan necesario pero no me acordaba de mas figuras XD

Answer (score 0):

Hice un esbozo sobre el tema del relleno, espero que te sirva:

```
opciones = {1:"Rombo", 2:"Cuadrado", 9:"Rellenar/Vaciar",99:"Terminar la ejecución"}
rellenar = False
relleno = " "

def rombo(n):
  l = [[" " for x in range(n)] for z in range(int(n/2+1))]
  for e in range(n):
    for i in range(e, n-e):
      l[e][i] = "*"
  l = l[:0:-1] + l
  for i in l:
    print(" ".join(i))


def cuadrado(lado):
  for i in range(lado):
    if i is 0:
      print("* "*(lado))
    elif i in[(lado-1)]:
      print("* "*(lado))
    else:
      print(("*"+relleno) + (relleno*2)*(lado-2) + "*")

def obtenerAncho():
  while True:
    op2 = input("Ingrese el ancho: ")
    if op2.isdigit() is True:
      return int(op2)
    return 0


while True:
  print("")
  print("Menú de opciones".center(30))
  print("-"*30)
  for opcion in list(opciones.keys()):
    print("[%d] %s" % (opcion, opciones[opcion]))

  op1 = input("\nIngrese una opción: ")
  if op1.isdigit() is True and int(op1) in list(opciones.keys()):
    if op1 == "1":
      rombo(obtenerAncho())
    elif op1 == "2":
      cuadrado(obtenerAncho())
    elif op1 == "9":
      rellenar = not rellenar
      print(" RELLENO ACTIVADO ".center(30,"=") if rellenar is True else " RELLENO DESACTIVADO ".center(30,"="))
      relleno = "#" if rellenar is True else " "
    elif op1 == "99":
      print("Hasta la vista baby")
      break
```